# Relabel the bins in a mosaic plot

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

In a mosaicplot, how do I relabel the bins?

```
dat <- data.frame(letters = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),
                  numbers = sample(3, 15, replace = TRUE))
mosaicplot(table(dat))
```

That is, how can I change the "A", "B", and "C" in the plot below to, say, "dogs", "cows", and "chicken"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to @MattTyers solution and a follow-up to the question whether everything can be done in one go: You can use the `formula` method for `mosaicplot()` and employ `factor()` inside the formula to assign new `labels` to the `levels` of the factor. Note that you need to set `xlab` and `ylab` explicitly in order not to have labels like `factor(..., labels = ...)`.

```
mosaicplot(~ factor(letters, labels = c("Aah", "Bee", "Cea")) +
  factor(numbers, labels = c("one", "two", "three")),
  data = dat, xlab = "Letters", ylab = "Numbers")
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to rename the table dims...

```
dat <- data.frame(letters = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),
                  numbers = sample(3, 15, replace = TRUE))

tab1 <- table(dat)
dimnames(tab1)[[1]] <- c("dogs","cows","chicken")
## note that dimnames(tab1)$letters <- c("dogs","cows","chicken") will work equally well

mosaicplot(tab1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do it without creating extra objects? That is, can the labels be added as an argument to either `table()` or `mosaicplot()`?